# How does firebase behave in case of a sudden spike in number of users?

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-firestore, firebase-app-check

We have

- a web based dart/flutter application with
- a firebase(firestore/storage/functions/appcheck) backend.

We plan a big launch event in March which will last exactly one hour.
So, at eg eleven o'clock sharp (+/- a couple of seconds),
we estimate that the number of users will increase from eg 100 to 100.000.
These users will all download our (web)app, do some read/writes on Firestore, make a call to a cloud function and do an appCheck.

Now I'm wondering what the impact is of such a spike:

- will Firebase scale fast enough
- are there Firestore limits we should consider
- how will AppCheck(reCaptchav3) behave when there is a sudden spike? Will it still assess every request individually or will it start blocking requests?

Anything else I might overlook?

Suggestions on how to test/simulate this upfront?

Looking forward to your input,

Marc

Comment: Known limits for Firestore are fully [documented](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/quotas).  If a limit isn't documented there, then it's not limited.  If you're experiencing a problem in production, reach out to [Firebase support](https://firebase.google.com/support).

Comment: I also recommend reading [Best practices for Cloud Firestore](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/best-practices), with specific attention to the section on [ramping up traffic](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/best-practices#ramping_up_traffic).

Comment: @DougStevenson Thanks! I vaguely remembered the following constraint, which I had to fetch from the internet archive  ("soft limit: Maximum sustained write rate to a document 1 per second; Sustaining a write rate above once per second increases latency and causes contention errors. This is not a hard limit, and you can surpass the limit in short bursts.").  We will have about 1000-10000 writes per second during one hour to a single document (just increment a counter) so I was wondering whether this would be an issue.

Comment: @FrankvanPuffelen: thanks for the pointer. Every group of users will have it's own collection so that should be fine. But I have one "summary" document which will (hopefully) get a lot of writes (~1000-10000 writes per second).  Should I, artificially, ramp up the number of writes to this document to be safe?

Comment: @DougStevenson, FrankvanPuffelen,  do you anticipate issues with hosting, cloud functions or appCheck?  Will this scale fast enough?

Answer (score 1):

Frequent writes to a single document are going to create a hotspot.

There is no way to ramp this up. Rather, you should shard the writes out across multiple documents, similar to what our documented [solution for a distributed counter](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/solutions/counters) does.

This is actually a core design principle for Firestore (and many other NoSQL databases), which favors making its reads (auto)scalable over making the writes scalable.

If you want to learn more about the internals of Firestore when it comes to write performance, I recommend reading the document on [understanding reads and writes at scale](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/understand-reads-writes-scale#understand_life_of_a_write_in).

Comment: Thanks for the links! I will implement the shards for my counter.  The details for read& write were also pretty interesting.  Note that the link to Key Visualizer (at the of https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/understand-reads-writes-scale) is broken.

Any idea how hosting, cloud functions and AppCheck will behave when a sudden spike occurs?